# How to copy a custom Objective-C object?

Tags: objective-c, object, copy, deep-copy, custom-object

I have a class, say the class Person. In than class I have several NSMutableArrays.

```
@property NSMutableArray *arrayOne;
@property NSMutableArray *arrayTwo;
...
```

Now I want to copy that Class so I can return it from a function and use the copy and change it's data. I want to have a new copy of the object in memory not another reference to the same address.

To do that I have implemented this in my Person.m:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    Person *copy = [[Person allocWithZone:zone] init;
    copy.arrayOne = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.arrayOne];
    copy.arrayTwo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.arrayTwo];
    ...

    return copy;
}
```

So far this works just like I want it to, but when I try to sort the arrays of the copy, I get an error: 
    -[__NSArrayI sortUsingSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100108a30

I have noticed that the original arrays are of the type '_*NSArrayM' but the copy is '*_NSArrayI'...

So what did I wrong? I have heard of deep copying using NSArchiver and NSUnarchiver... Do I have to use that? Sorry, I am quite new to C and Objective-C... :D

I hope you can help me out of this. =)

Sorry about my 'school-english'....

Cheers,
Nick

EDIT: The arrays consist of NSString objects, so I can use

```
sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)
```

to sort the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are your mutable array properties being declared in your header file?

```
// Wrong
@property (copy) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (assign) NSMutableArray *array;

// Right
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *array;
```

NB If you're just doing

```
@property NSMutableArray *array;
```

then I'm amazed your code has got this far :) The default property memory semantics is `assign` - which won't tell ARC to retain your arrays in any way at all :) You need to specify `strong`.

Comment: Thanks you you for you answer. I used (copy). Sorry I did not copy my code into my post so i forgot about that. I now use (strong) and it works fine. Thanks you very much.

Comment: It's really annoying - I would have expected that `copy` on a property would make a mutable copy - instead you pass in a mutable array and your object gets an immutable copy. IMHO that's a bug with properties :)

Comment: Yeah. Like I said I am new to Objective-C so I am doing learning by doing right now and I haven't really understood properties yet. :D With ARC is it okay to just use (weak) and (strong)? Thank you again for your friendly support!

Comment: It's a good idea to use `copy` instead of strong if your property is something which has a mutable subclass (i.e. you should copy NSArray, NSString, NSSet etc). Use `strong` for objects that you want to own, and use `weak` for properties like delegates i.e. things that you want to know about but are't owned by your object. Finally use `assign` for things that aren't objects.